# Checkbox accent unchecked checkbox

Tags: android, material-design

**Question**

Is there a way how to color the default unchecked checkbox color? This is the state now:

[image: current state]

I want the UNCHECKED checkbox to have the accented color (the blue in my case) as it is in the checked variant.

**My configuration**

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'

<item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can display a checkbox in any shape and color you like.

add a drawable `custom_checkbox.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_checked="true" 
      android:drawable="@xml/checked" /> 
<item android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@xml/checked" /> 
<item android:drawable="@xml/unchecked" /> 
</selector>
```

now you can specify how `checked`and `unchecked` should look like:

checked.xml:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- set whatever color you like -->
<stroke android:width="2px" android:color="@color/accent" />
<size android:height="20dp" android:width="20dp"/>
</shape>
```

unchecked.xml:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<stroke android:width="2px" android:color="#ffc0c0c0" />
<size android:height="20dp" android:width="20dp"/>
</shape>
```

Now you can set the `android:button` attribute of your checkbox to `@drawable/custom_checkbox` and you should see your own colored checkbox!

The code is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24925997/1024057).

Comment: Thank you for help! But the solution is working only partialy. It indeed colours the frame to blue but checked state is missing the "V". It is just plain frame too. I need to find out how to link the checked state to the original checkbox. Any ideas?

Comment: @zatziky The default selector is this one here: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable/btn_check.xml

Comment: `@android:drawable/btn_check`, I guess.

Comment: the default selector is \@android:drawable/checkbox_on_background. The problem is that it's a picture. Anyway, thanks for help.